# Is it possible to receive an EditText from an xml activity to java that's not connected to the xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

I have an XML that has an edit text on it, a java file connected to it that can receive the edit text and turn into a string no problem

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.coopery.notes.NoteActivity"
android:background="#da141415">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etTitle"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:hint="Title..."
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etNote"
    android:layout_below="@id/etTitle"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:background="@null"
    android:hint="Note..."
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
```

---

**Java**

```
public class NoteActivity extends Activity {

Typeface customFont;

EditText etTitle;
EditText etNote;

String oldTitle;
AlarmPage A = new AlarmPage();
Notification.Builder notification;
NotificationManager manager;
private String Title, Note1, Note;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note);



    String fileName = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_TITLE);
    oldTitle = fileName;

    etTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
    etNote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNote);

    String Title = etTitle.getText().toString();
    String Note = etNote.getText().toString();
```

---

but another java file when I try to get the same code, it get's a null. How could I do it?

If I'm not specific enough, please let me know, it's a bit of a hard question to ask.
Here's the method from the other java file which I am trying to use and receive the edittext

```
 public void notification() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note);
    EditText TitleE, NoteE;

    TitleE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
    NoteE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNote);

    String Title, Note;

    Title = TitleE.getText().toString();
    Note = NoteE.getText().toString();


    //both PingService and CommonConstants java files are needed for this method


    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(Title)
            .setContentText(Note)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) // requires VIBRATE 
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("hi"));
```

Note: I put a second setContentView to see if it worked, it didn't.

Comment: In the method `setContentView(R.layout.activity_note);` you specify the xml file you are using, and when in another activity it is different, you can not access elements from the first one. Put in the layout of the second Activity the same EditText you want, else it is not possible to access it

Comment: can you post the errors that you are getting? I mean logcat

Comment: I think the error log is not necessary, because I think it is clear that the exception is that the EditText, when accessed from the second Activity is null, because it is not present in the current layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify enTitle and enNote declaration like this, this will make them global across all your activities:

```
public static EditText etTitle;
public static EditText etNote;
```

Then you'll be able to get their values from other activities, however if you try to change them from other activities, you'll get an exception.

If someone else will modify your code, it's better to make these variables private, and create two methods instead:

```
public static String getTitle() {
    return enTitle.getText().toString();
};
public static String getNote() {
    return enNote.getText().toString();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the edittext as public static in class A

public static EditText title;

Now you can access this edittext in class B

A.title